# IIS 7 Window Server 2008 - WCF service timing out

Tags: silverlight, wcf, iis, timeout

I have a WCF Service for a Silverlight Application that can perform a few thousand inserts to an SQL Server database. Normally everything works fine but when we have a large set of data the service takes a longer time to do the work.

On my local IIS server (Win XP, IIS 5) and my ASP.Net dev server (even when not in debug mode) I can run the request for a long time until the job is done. I have set the Client side silverlight EndPoints timeouts/buffer sizes to a large amount (20 minutes etc..).

When we deploy to live (IIS 7 / Win 2008 Server) for some reason the service times out dead on 2 minutes. It's not the service thats stopped running because the log file is still being written to whilst Silverlight shows a "Not Found" error for the async callback method.

Where on earth is the setting on IIS that controls the timeout? I know their are 5 or so different setting for timeouts that can be set in the web.config. However, no setting I change in IIS has any effect (forms authentication has a timeout, wcf has one etc..).

Please bare in mind that this app and web.config works perfectly ok on IIS 5 / Win XP. Finally, do I have to restart IIS for any timeout changes to to effect? I am reluctant to do this because its a live server and there are other applications running on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try [changing the connectionTimeout for the web site](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/sites/siteDefaults/limits). Looks like the default is two minutes.